# Using pysmbc to read files over samba

Tags: python, samba

I am using the python-smbc library on Ubuntu to access a samba share. I can access the directory structure fine, I am however not sure how to access actual files and their content. The webpage (https://fedorahosted.org/pysmbc/) doesn't mention any thing, the code is in C/C++, with little documentation, so I am not quite sure how to use it.

What I know is that Context.open (for files) takes uri, flags and mode, but what flags and mode are, I don't know.

Has anyone used this library, or have examples off how to read files using it?

The ideal situation had of course been to use smbfs mounts, but when I mount the same share using smbmount, all folders are empty. Though I can browse it with smbclient fine using the same credentials.

Answer (score 12):

I also have had trouble using smbfs (random system lockdowns and reboots) and needed a quick answer.

I've also tried the `smbc` module but couldn't get any data with it. I went just as far as accessing the directory structure, just like you.

Time was up and I had to deliver the code, so I took a shortcut:

I wrote a small wrapper around a "`smbclient`" call. It is a hack, ugly, **really ugly**, but it works for my needs. It is being used in production on the company I work.

Here's some example usage:

```
>>> smb = smbclient.SambaClient(server="MYSERVER", share="MYSHARE", 
                                username='foo', password='bar', domain='baz')
>>> print smb.listdir(u"/")
[u'file1.txt', u'file2.txt']
>>> f = smb.open('/file1.txt')
>>> data = f.read()
>>> f.close()
>>> smb.rename(u'/file1.txt', u'/file1.old')
```

The programmer before me was using a "bash" file with lots of smbclient calls, 
so I think my solution is at least better.

I have uploaded it [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySmbClient), so you can use it if you want. Bitbucket repository is [here](http://bitbucket.org/nosklo/pysmbclient/). If you find a better solution please tell me and I'll replace my code too.

Comment: Hi sir, it's good module , but not working in Python 2.6.8  and below

Comment: @RahulPatil how is it failing? I'm using it on python 2.4 and 2.5 here in production and it works. Can you open a issue at the issue tracker and describe the error you're getting here: https://bitbucket.org/nosklo/pysmbclient/issues/new

Comment: dude your wrapper flipping rocks i love it awesome!

Comment: @nosklo can you give me access to your repository please?

Answer (score 3):

Provided you have an open context (see the unit tests here)
 * https://github.com/ioggstream/pysmbc/tree/master/tests

```
suri =  'smb://' + settings.SERVER + '/' + settings.SHARE + '/test.dat'  
dpath = '/tmp/destination.out'

# open smbc uri
sfile = ctx.open(suri, os.O_RDONLY)

# open local target where to copy file
dfile = open(dpath, 'wb')

#copy file and flush
dfile.write(sfile.read())
dfile.flush()

#close both files
sfile.close()    
dfile.close()
```

To open a context just define an authentication function

```
ctx = smbc.Context()

def auth_fn(server, share, workgroup, username, password):
    return (workgroup, settings.USERNAME, settings.PASSWORD)

ctx.optionNoAutoAnonymousLogin = True
ctx.functionAuthData = auth_fn
```

Comment: I just needed a simple thing and this is just it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If don't know if this is more clearly stated, but here's what I gleaned from this page and sorted out from a little extra Google-ing:

```
def do_auth (server, share, workgroup, username, password):
  return ('MYDOMAIN', 'myacct', 'mypassword')


# Create the context
ctx = smbc.Context (auth_fn=do_auth)
destfile = "myfile.txt"
source = open('/home/myuser/textfile.txt', 'r')
# open a SMB/CIFS file and write to it
file = ctx.open ('smb://server/share/folder/'+destfile, os.O_CREAT | os.O_WRONLY)
for line in source:
        file.write (line)
file.close()
source.close()

# open a SMB/CIFS file and read it to a local file
source = ctx.open ('smb://server/share/folder/'+destfile, os.O_RDONLY)
destfile = "/home/myuser/textfile.txt"
fle = open(destfile, 'w')
for line in source:
        file.write (line)
file.close()
source.close()
```

Comment: Can you explain more how this answers the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you've managed to get the directory structure then you have a working context. The key to actually accessing files is the undocumented flags argument of `Context.open`.  (I haven't figured out what mode is for either but it doesn't seem necessary.)

`flags` is how you tell pysmbc what type of access to the file you want. You do that by passing it an integer made by bitwise ORing (`|`) flags from the os module together. Specifically the flags you want or suffixed with `os.O_` (see a list in the Python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#open-flag-constants)).

For example, to write to a file you would set flags to `os.O_WRONLY` (equiavlent to using `"w"` as the mode parameter of the built in `open` function) and to append to a file that might already exist use `os.O_WRONLY | os.O_APPEND | os.O_CREAT` (equivalent to `"a+"`).

That call will then return a `file` object which you can use like any normal, local file.

Answer (score -3):

I would stick with smbfs.  It's only a matter of time before you want to access those shared files with something other than Python.