# Mapping a network drive to a letter in Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, networking, share, drive

couldn't find any helpful answer till now.
I have to copy a file from the Linux-Machine to a Windows Share Drive / Samba Share (username and password protected) using Python 2.7.3

How can I map a network drive to a letter in Python?

Comment: Why do you need to map the network drive to a letter? Why not just use a UNC path?

Comment: Do you mean that the network share on the windows machine is currently not set up and you want to create a new network drive via python? Does it have to create a share just to copy the file? Can you use a lib to just copy the file you want?

Comment: On Windows you can make a drive from the command line using the `net` command, `net use m: \\financial\letters\mike` for example -- so you could do something similar using the `os.system()` function or `subprocess` module.

Comment: UNC path doesn't work. Yes, just the file should be copied. I am able to copy the file from one folder to another but not to network share. For this I am using "shutil.copyfile". Do you know in which sequence user name and password of the network share should be entered?

Comment: The description of the command syntax [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/net-use-command.htm) shows how to pass _username_ and _password_ as arguments to the `net use` command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use samba ... read the file and just save it

if it is large, read it by bytes at row, not at once ...

[Using pysmbc to read files over samba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986730/using-pysmbc-to-read-files-over-samba)

And if you really, really want the script to make the letter, use solution above with net use, or win32 or windll, one of them will for sure have something direct, but with windows it is always difficult to find out a way to use script, so the simplest way is just copy the file and don't map it ...

Enjoy

Comment: both linux machine and network share are in the same network. The file should be copied automatically and not manually. How is it possible "to explain" to the machine via python, that network share is an external drive?

Comment: So the linux machine is samba server, and you want to connect to it from windows and copy some file, but one thing I still don't understand is why do you need to use some external drives, just run the script from client, the script will handle samba layer, and from that script just save the file to local disk, right? Try to give me more info about what are you trying to achieve

Comment: No. Linux machine is a reader device connected to network. The file is on this device and should be copied to a network share, which is password protected. How can I implement it in python? I tried this and it worked: source_path=r"/Folder A, dest_path=r"/Folder B, file_name="aaa", shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source_path, file_name), os.path.join(dest_path, file_name)). But when I use something like dest_path=r"\\Network Name\Folder C, the file can not be copied.

Comment: well, so you need to access samba like this, linux client, windows is sharing the folder with write permissions, so on linux you need to mount the windows share, that depends on your distribution, you need to install smbfs, or cifs then just mount it like this 'mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=pass \\ip_addr_of_shared\dir \mnt\local\folder'  you need to mount the file first on linux machine, then use regular copy, for automatic mounting of the network drive, add line to your /etc/fstab, but that is distribution specific, if you need to use python only

Comment: if you need python only, python needs to handle samba protocol, so use smbc, but there is not much available documentation, so still the best way would be to make sure that the drive is mounted on linux, you would need to call 'mount' then parse it to find if it is mounted or not, and call mount as described above via subprocess.call that calls external os commands, or use pysmbc library as mentioned above

Comment: thanks for your help.I am not really experienced in python. Could you please explain:1.how can I install smbfs? 2.Do I have to unmount after copying the file? And how?

Comment: this is not python related, what is your linux distribution? usually these kind of information are found at wiki.linux_distro.org or google mount samba distro_name .. there should be more info .. on debian/ubuntu it is 'sudo apt-get install cifs-utils', after that you can 'mount -t cifs.....' as mentioned above

Comment: Sorry, I need python only. The reader-device is just working on linux, but the code should by in python.

Comment: In that case, follow link above, pysmbc